# Survival analysis but with cost outcome

Tags: survival, loss-functions

For example, let us suppose we have patients who may be alive (state = 0) or dead (state = 1). But, when a patient dies at time $t$, there is a certain treatment cost $C(t)$ incurred at death (no cost during times prior to $t$). Note that $C(t)$ itself is a randomly distributed variable with the distribution being a function of time. We are now interested in estimating the life-time treatment cost of the population. Are there some survival analysis-like approaches to deal with this problem?

Comment: In HEOR we consider the costs over a fixed period, like 1, 5, or 20 years or their whole lifetime. A subject who dies prior to follow-up incurs no additional costs after that point. A subject who outlives the follow-up period may be censored. A subject who withdraws prior to the follow-up period requires imputation. Curious if anyone else in this area has done otherwise.

Comment: I see. I think I may have not been clear enough. Edited the question accordingly. In my scenario, the treatment cost is not incurred over the lifetime of the individual, it is only incurred at death.

Comment: Still not a well defined problem unfortunately. On one hand, it's obvious to me, based on how you worded the question, to either present two separate analyses (cost given death, and then time to death), or to do a total cost analysis. In either case, it should be clear that "money doesn't survive" - so the integrated analysis you are envisioning either doesn't make sense, or would answer the wrong question.

Comment: Here's a nice example from literature. In this analysis, this popular myth about non-use of helmet on a motorcycle is debunked https://ajph.aphapublications.org/doi/pdf/10.2105/AJPH.86.1.41 The myth specifically is that it's better *not* to wear a helmet because, when you crash you just die on the highway, rather than getting hospitalized for multiple reasons and dying in care. This should be a good example to modify for whatever your analysis is.

Comment: If you know a functional form for $C(t)$ and have a modeled estimate of the distribution of survival times, then this might be a simple application of the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). It's not completely clear from the question, however, whose cost you are modeling and what you mean by "$C(t)$ itself is a randomly distributed variable with the distribution being a function of time." Please edit the question to provide more information about those matters, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.